# page Data transfer Size

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to get size of data that page request or get from server even if my request is in ajax.(in browser developer tools or asp.net via code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser can do this:

In chrome/safari use developer tools and click on Resources.

In Firefox install Firebug and click on Net.

Comment: thanks a lot. i'm getting blind :D working with firebug for several month and didn't see that